# Python- no module named 'azure'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, azure

I am trying to use Azure's computervision API, but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "lala.py", line 2, in <module>
 from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
```

I have installed client library through `pip install --upgrade azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision`.

I am still getting this error. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: type **<<cmd that you use python to execute python or python3>> -m pip freeze** see if azure is in there

Comment: `pip install azure` or `pip install azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision`  https://pypi.org/project/azure/

Comment: Recommend to use virtualenv or miniconda (Anaconda) with a specific environment for your project. You should create a requierments.txt or conda-env.yml. For conda see [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually). If you share this file, anyone who want to help can simulate your environment and check whether the import works on her/his side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on my experience, the issue like yours was normally caused by the name confliction in Python.

Please open a Python interpreter in the current path of your `lala.py` file and type the code below to show the path list of packages imported.

```
import sys
sys.path
# The result should be like as below.
# A virtualenv path on Windows, ['', '<your virtualenv path>\\Scripts\\python37.zip', '<your virtualenv path>\\DLLs', '<your virtualenv path>\\lib', '<your virtualenv path>\\Scripts', 'c:\\python37\\Lib', 'c:\\python37\\DLLs', '<your virtualenv path>', '<your virtualenv path>\\lib\\site-packages']
# A virtualenv path on Linux, ['', '<your virtualenv path>/lib/python36.zip', '<your virtualenv path>/lib/python3.6', '<your virtualenv path>/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '<your virtualenv path>/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

Python will import packages searched from the path listed in order, so please inspect your current path whether there be a directory or file named `azure`, then you need to rename the name conflicted one.

For example, I created a virtualenv directory for testing, and I created a directory named `azure` with a file `__init__.py` in it, then I tried to run my `lala.py` file and I got the similar issue with yours, as the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually created a new virtual environment and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Could you please install via

```
pip install azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision
```

So without the `--upgrade` flag. I know, in the docs they recommend to use the flag but actually this one is for upgrading a already installed package and it seems it is not installed in your environment yet.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, and azure is in there when run >>pip freeze also

Comment: Probably @Peter Pan has the solution. Check his answer. I recommend to study the basic importing scheme of Python which will help to prevent such issues again. See a good explanation [here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).

Comment: you may have to use pip3 install azure-some-long-library (that's pip3, not pip)